# SVM in OpenCV: low accuracy OCR with RBF kernel

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opencv, machine-learning, svm

I'm going on with my project of OCR using MS Visual Studio 2008, OpenCV, C++ and SVM. I've generated a dataset of > 2000 samples of machine-printed characters. When I test with linear kernel, I always get 96,36% accuracy rate.

How I use SVM in OpenCV can be referred in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621110/svm-in-opencv-throws-cvexception-at-memory-location).

Now I try to use RBF kernel and encounter these 2 problems:

(1) No matter what parameters (C and gamma) I used, all the characters were always classified to 0 (zero). If I test with MNIST all of the digits are 9.

I hope someone with experience in OpenCV & SVM can explain to me. I know there're some other good frameworks for machine learning & image processing like ACCORD.NET, but I've already used C++ and it would be troublesome to turn the whole program into C# (OCR is only a part of it).

The version of OpenCV is 2.3.1.

(2) I moved this problem to another question as suggestion of *etarion*. If you have time please check it out: [Visual Studio reports error C2664 with train method of SVM in openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809722/svm-in-opencv-visual-studio-2008-reported-error-wrongly-or-is-it-right).

Comment: Multi-part questions like this are not suited for the stackoverflow format - it's better if you ... well, post one question per question.

Comment: Something is definitely wrong, the RBF kernel should perform reasonably well if the linear kernel is performing that well. When you say 'No matter what values of C & gamma', can you say which values you are using? You generally vary these in orders of magnitude, so C = 0.0001 0.001 0.01 0.1 1 5 10 and gamma is similar.  I've seen people think they are varying it because they try 5, 10, 15, 20 when they need to try 0.0001, etc. The value of C that worked for the linear kernel won't necessarily work for the rbf kernel.

Comment: @etarion: Well, they're both about openCV and SVM, even thought the root of problems are different, but if I post 2 continuous separated questions I'd feel like I'm spamming :P

Comment: @karenu: I tested from C = 0.0001 to C = 1000, so did with gamma (yes, I've tested like crazy for a week) and can't figure out the reason. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: Yes, that is the right ranges generally.

Comment: @Risa: It's just not possible to rate answers partially - and you can only accept one answer ... if it's different questions, just post two questions.

Comment: @etarion: OK, I'll do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theory suggests that under the correct parameters an RBF kernel works at least as well as a linear kernel. Therefore I will list common sources of problems:

- It is possible that you're having numerical difficulties. Have you normalized your data? Is every feature between 0 and 1? or -1 and 1? What is the numerical range of the actual decision values? What is the range of the feature values?
- Is it possible that you're overestimating the performance of the linear classifier (i.e. test and train on the same data?)
- Could it be that your multi class representation is somehow flawed. Does the same performance difference hold for a two class problem instead of a ten class problem?

Comment: 1. I train every 2 class and save the results of training into files (you can see how I do it in the linked question on the right column of this page, I'm not sure I did it right, but it works with linear kernel anyway). Temporarily my feature vector contains only 0 & 1 elements.
2. I use different data: 2000+ for training and 200+ for testing (no sample in testing set belongs to training set).
3. I also tried to solve 2 class problem and it still went wrong. I think it's not the case because of the way I build the machines.
 Thank you for your concern.

Comment: @Risa so, since you accepted the answer provided can you share which was the problem in your implementation with the rest of us?

Answer (score 0):

As for the first part, it's very likely that your parameters are off. There's a [train_auto method](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvm-train-auto) for automatic parameter estimation, you can extend the used parameter ranges if those don't yield nice results by passing custom parameter grids to the method (but try the default parameters first).

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I've already tested with the default parameters and train_auto method but still no luck :( Now I can't test with other grids due to problem #2.

Comment: @Risa: The other thing is maybe due to two seperate opencv installations, one older and one newer, with the older (which does not have the cv::Mat interface) one being picked when compiling, and you get the tooltip from the more recent one.

Comment: I have only installed openCV once by far :( Before that I was using ACCORD.NET for a quite short time (my professor said that C# is slower than C++, so I switched). Btw why everytime I add '@etarion' in this comment, the word disappears?